# View of taxonomy terms - add preprocess class

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, theming

I have a view showing taxonomy terms with an images field. I'd like to add a class .has-images if the images field is not empty.

I've done this before with nodes using preprocess, have tried something similar and have looked around for an answer though I can't seem to get it to work. Also where would the code go? would it go in a view.preprocess.inc file?

This is an example of node.preprocess.inc

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
 if(!empty($vars['field_images'])) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'has-images';
 }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can be done with Views. On image field use 'REWRITE RESULTS' to add class in wrapper div, and in 'NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR' make sure 'Hide rewriting if empty' is ticked.

Comment: @J.Reynolds that would work, though that adds the class to the images field. I need it to add a class to the list item .views-row so that I can effect the width of the text based on if there are images. Currently there is just a large gap.

Answer (score 0):

You should try hook_views_pre_render(&$view);
http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7

Also you can write a template file to write extra css class with condtion. For this go to advance section and go for theming section and choose a template name.